# Missing cpu.cfs_period_us cgroup subsystem in Raspbian Stretch on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: linux, raspbian-stretch, pi-zero, kernel, debian

I'm dabbling about with cgroups on my Raspberry Pi Zero using the latest version of Raspbian Stretch and I was surprised to see only the following `cpu` cgroup subsystems available:

```
cgroup.clone_children  cpuacct.usage         cpuacct.usage_percpu_sys   cpuacct.usage_user  tasks
cgroup.procs           cpuacct.usage_all     cpuacct.usage_percpu_user  cpu.shares
cpuacct.stat           cpuacct.usage_percpu  cpuacct.usage_sys          notify_on_release
```

I'd like to be able to set `cpu.cfs_period_us` and `cpu.cfs_quota_us`. Is that possible?

Additional info:

```
Linux localhost 4.14.50+ #1122 Tue Jun 19 12:21:21 BST 2018 armv6l GNU/Linux

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
Release:    9.4
Codename:   stretch
```

Comment: Hello - I've been asked to review your post as it's your first. It's an interesting question. I've not tried to use `cgroups`, but a quick read suggests they may need to be enabled before they're available. It might help you get a good answer if you could explain how you determined what subsystems were available, and how you've enabled them.

Comment: `I was surprised to see only the following` - that seems to be the *default* case - you say you were *surprised* - why? What made you think there's be more than that?

Comment: I'm just not very familiar with Raspbian. I'm used to interacting with them on servers that have ample resources and have this particular functionality available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's because Raspbian is not compiled with the `CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH` flag enabled. There are concerns that the presence of it would cause additional overhead and affect the performance of Raspbian. Found this in the cgroups man page:

> In Linux 3.2, this controller was extended to provide CPU
>   "bandwidth" control.  If the kernel is configured with CON‐
>   FIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH, then within each scheduling period (defined
>   via a file in the cgroup directory), it is possible to define
>   an upper limit on the CPU time allocated to the processes in a
>   cgroup.  This upper limit applies even if there is no other
>   competition for the CPU.  Further information can be found in
>   the kernel source file Documentation/scheduler/sched-bwc.txt.

**References:**

- https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2298
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html